# How can I discover all of my EC2 instances behind a ELB that have a specific tag

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Can someone post a snippet or point me in the right direction in regards to how I can discover a collection of EC2 instances that are behind a specific Elastic Load Balancer and that have a specific tag assigned to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty, using the ELB and EC2 command line tools:

```
elb-describe-instance-health <load balancer name>
```

Will return a list of instances in an ELB and their status.

```
ec2-describe-instances <instance id>
```

Will return information about the instances, including their tags. You could put together a simple shell script to look through the instances in an ELB and check the tags.

ELB documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingTheCommandLineTools.html

EC2 documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SettingUp_CommandLine.html

There's also the newer CLI that integrates access to many AWS services: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html

I haven't worked with C# with AWS, but they do have an SDK for it: http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/

Answer (score 0):

I would have to know why you have set it up this way and have a bunch of EC2 instances with tags that you want balanced? If they are all running say a java web application WAR, then this can be done using the automated service Elastic Bean Stalk. This takes care of the elastic load balancer, and auto scaling the amount and size of the ec2 instances connecting to load balancer.

Amazon is able to "preheat" EBS for you if your about to say go from testing to launch.

If you just have a bunch of EC2 instances running a process and just want to collect the ones with tags... then I think you would need to explore the SDK. And look at how to return all the ec2 instances with your tag, and then use the sdk to add them to your load balancer if they aren't there. If you start down this process I can offer advice for Java dev.